# How to give elastivity an Object without rigging in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to create a pole vault game and I need to Bend the stick that player uses when player makes the jump. I tried mesh deformer and many other tols but i am at beginner level  i can not handle it properly so ,Is there any simple solution without using rigged stick.